# Only allow certain IPs to be reached on an Ubuntu box

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I am after the simplest, most straightforward way to prevent access to ANY site except a few whitelisted ones from a Linux (Ubuntu) box.

Can it be done easily with IP filtering? Say for example that I only want to allow access to 3.213.91.1 (any port) and NOTHING else. How could I do that in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You set up a simple firewall script like

```
  #/bin/bash
  iptables -I INPUT -j DROP
  iptables -I INPUT -s 3.213.91.1 -j ACCEPT
```

There are, ofcourse many variations on the above theme.  This sets a deny all rule and then inserts an exception before it.  Note it assumes you dont need DNS (implied by your question wording but maybe not what you want).  It also assumes you ate blocking traffic destined for this machine, rather then traffic going through it.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear... I want to block traffic STARTING from this machine, and I would love to keep DNS!